# Adjective use after nouns: with and without that-clause

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives, relative-clauses, whiz-deletion

Let us take a look at these adjectives:
*able, similar, capable, ready,* etc.
We are free to stick them to the back of any noun thus avoiding using *that/who*-clause, like in these examples:

> Presumably, a person *able* to part with that kind of money...
>
> ...a savoury cake with a texture *similar* to that of carrot cake...

But we cannot do the same trick with, for example, *identical, harmless, safe*, and many other adjectives. At least, I was not lucky to find any examples. All we can do with them is to use *that*-clause:

> ...to smell a fragrance that is *identical* to that of a real rose...
>
> ...find a place that is *safe* to stay...
>
> ...use the stuff that is *harmless* to the body...

Is there any rule or algorithm to figure out which adjectives I can glue or cannot glue to the back of nouns directly?

Comment: But these are all normal: to smell a fragrance identical to that of a real rose, find a place safe to stay, use the stuff harmless to the body.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin
I cannot find any examples from reliable sources, where these or other similar adjectives are glued to any noun in a way I described above.

Comment: @YosefBaskin is correct; there is no problem with these reduced relative clauses: *to smell a fragrance identical to that of a real rose, find a place safe to stay, use the stuff harmless to the body*. (And they aren't *that*-clauses, which are something altogether different.)

Comment: @YosefBaskin
There are no examples of these norms from reliable sources, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know why you think the AdJPs cannot function directly (i.e. as post-head modifiers). They can, and NPs like _a fragrance identical to that of a real rose_ and _a place safe to stay_ are fine.

Comment: @BillJ 
The absence of examples in good sources is that reason.
But since the topic is closed I think I should use another website.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/identical) has ‘For the final day, Torrance has picked an outfit identical to the one he wore while sinking that putt 17 years ago.’ and ‘Some of the ‘actors’ live lives identical to the parts they play in the movie.’ So I'm not sure what is a better source than Oxford Dictionaries.

Comment: If BillJ and I agree on something, you can assume most other Anglophones do too. // Post-modification using classifying adjectives looks dodgy (??A reaction nuclear in its nature).

Comment: @Stuart F Thank you for examples. I would like to widen the question by noticing that grammar is not the sole purpose of my question and style is also an object of my concern. So what I had had before I dared to ask this were numerous examples of *that*-clauses utilized to cram the above mentioned adjectives into spaces behind nouns, and no cases of their being glued directly. Strictly speaking, *that*-clauses prevail and are preferred in these situations. So, which construction is more beautiful? Maybe both look dodgy?

Comment: 'A man brave' is unacceptable (though 'a man brave and true' might get by in lyrics) while 'a man brave enough to stand with Gandalf against the approaching terror' is fine. 'Padding' often licenses.

Comment: [Does this look at whiz-deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650) (ex John Lawler) help?

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

The question presents three adjectives that, it is claimed, cannot directly follow a noun, but require to be preceded by “that is”. Examples are provided from a variety of linguistically respectable sources over the past 200 years that challenge the universality of this claim. It possible that omission of “that is” in such cases is more common for certain adjectives than others, but this reflects usage rather than any grammatical or linguistic rule.

**Counter-examples**

The method I adopted to find counter-examples was to formulate phrases of the type “indefinite-article noun adjective preposition”, where the adjective was one of harmless, safe or identical.  This was placed in double quotation marks to allow a Google search for this exact phrase. Clearly the results depend on the choice of noun, which is subjective, reflecting my own vocabulary and interests. However the same can be said of the examples in the question. I provide two examples for each adjective

> [The fact is that there exists in anaphylactized blood a *substance
> harmless* in itself but which releases a strong poison when mixed with
> the antigen.](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/medicine/1913/richet/lecture/)
> [Charles Richet, Nobel Prize Lecture, 1913]

> [The emblem of the game cock is I think superior to any of them; he is an *animal
> harmless* and inoffensive to all his neighbours, but when opposed he never leaves
> his enemy but with victory or death.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30074901?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)
> [Letter to the Belfast Monthly Magazine, 1814]

> [Also, images of the “army of beauties” rather than parades involving
> intercontinental ballistic missiles is more likely to convince the
> international audience that South Korea is a *country safe* to visit,
> and not under the threat of impending
> war.](https://asiasociety.org/korea/north-korean-cheering-squad)
> [Mark Sample, Asia Society, 2018]

> [A *place safe* from theft and destruction](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=olwVZ4qiHe0C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22A+place+safe+from+theft+and+destruction%22&source=bl&ots=AVWKewcLs-&sig=ACfU3U1MPeaKYY4y58gQG-T_hx2mOunYGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXiMKomMD1AhWJZMAKHZJxDbEQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22A%20place%20safe%20from%20theft%20and%20destruction%22&f=false)
> [Description of Heaven, Rose Book of Bible Charts, Maps, and Time Lines, 2015]

> [The Hulthén method is shown to give a *result identical* to the Harris
> method at the energy eigenvalues characteristic of the
> latter.](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.175.134)
> [R.K. Nesbet, *Physical Review*, 1968]

> [Don’t allow a new user to post an *answer identical* to one of his/her previous answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110206/dont-allow-a-new-user-to-post-an-answer-identical-to-one-of-his-her-previous-an/110207#110207)
> [Post on *StackExchange Meta*, 2011]

**Possible explanations of different frequency of omission of “that is”**

If it is indeed true that some adjectives occur less frequently in the type of construction described in the question this may possibly reflect frequency of use. Certainly one can think of examples of catch phrases in which “that is” is omitted, e.g. [“Homes fit for Heroes”](http://www.socialhousinghistory.uk/wp/homes-fit-for-heroes/). The omission in more formal and academic writing cited would seem to contradict this, but here it might reflect a desire to shorten sentences that are necessarily complex.

Comment: these sources cannot be considered reliable since these are just technical writings and a second-grade news blog. Misprints, mistakes, wrong usage and all like that are also done by natives from time to time, but it doesn't mean we should cite exclusions to prove the whole.

Comment: @Fridge — Please read my revised answer with additional examples. These are provided to support my own contention — and that of several knowledgable commenters — that the construction without "that is" does not appear unnatural, and is found in reputable writing of different types over a period of 200 years. It may well be that the frequency of use varies with different adjectives, and, if so must be a question of usage rather than rules. I would suggest that you are misusing the word "reliable". It seems to be a device for rejecting any examples you wish. A more objective word is required.

Comment: "Fridge They constitute more compelling evidence than the claim "I cannot find any examples [in] reliable sources" and better scholarship than assuming that that claim justifies "The absence of examples in good sources".

Comment: @David So, what we have in this very thread are a few examples mostly produced by some 'technical individuals' within the period of 200 years. It is a remarkable discovery, isn't' it? What if I assumed that the answer to all this lies in the field of stylistics, i.e it is not commonly preferred to utilize these adjectives behind nouns at all. I would be glad to hear your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @Fridge — I don't really have any more thoughts on this matter because I lack the factual basis that could make them useful. I would make one observation. The written record of the English language until, say the end of the 19th century comprises works by the educated classes — clerics, scholars, officials, professionals and military officers. This was supplemented by poets and later novelists. However, if you look at the quotations in the OED you will see that they are mainly from "some Technical Individuals".